# Spring - Why returning value was shown XML Type in Screen?

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, maven

I have a problem.
I'm using Spring framework and I want to return Json data

When I call, It returns XML Type in the Postman.

but printed Json Type in Console

this is Controller

```
@Autowired
MobileUserService mobileUserService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/mobile/mobileuser.do")
@ResponseBody
public HashMap<String, Object> selectUser(
        @RequestParam(value="userId", required = false) String userId,
        @RequestParam(value="userPwd", required = false) String userPwd,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    HashMap<String, Object> selectMap = mobileUserService.selectUser(userId, userPwd);

    System.out.println("userid: " + userId + "userPW : " + userPwd);

    if(selectMap == null) {
        selectMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        selectMap.put("code", -1);
        selectMap.put("msg", "Check ID or Password");
    }else {
        selectMap.put("code", 0);
        selectMap.put("msg", "Success");
    }
    System.out.println("sdfsdfsdf " + selectMap);
    return selectMap;
}
```

and I added dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

server-context.xml

```
<bean id=“jacksonMessageConverter” class=“org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter”/>
```

How could I that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your request mapping to

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!